# OleDb SQLDATASOURCE can't select wildcard data

Tags: asp.net, oledb, wildcard, sqldatasource

I've been tasked with applying sql parameters to a web page that's been identified as having a sql injection point.  The originator used the typical inline sql string that is composed to do a wildcard search.  I've read in various posts in Stackoverflow about trying several selection methods and using different concatenation methods.  I've settled on one approach that seems the most reasonable, though I am open to other suggestions. I know that since the page uses an OleDb connection, the would be @parameters are replaced with ?.

**Original vb source selection:**

```
VendorsSDS.SelectCommand = "Select ... and vnmdesc like '%" & UCase(Trim(txtRefine.Text)) & "%'"
```

**Original aspx:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtRefine" name="txtRedfine" runat="server" Width="163px" MaxLength="5"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" DataSourceID="VendorsSDS"
        DataTextField="VNMDESC" DataValueField="VENDORID" Height="206px" Width="463px" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:ListBox>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="VendorsSDS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString5 %>"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString5.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="Select VNMKVPRE||VNMKVNBR as VendorID, vnmdesc||' - '||VNMKVPRE||VNMKVNBR as vnmdesc from trmsd.avnmp   where VNMST = 'A' and not trim(vnmdesc) = '' and vnmkvpre in ( 'R', 'V', 'X')  order by VNMDESC ">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My direction is to utilize <asp:SelectParameters> and an <asp:ControlParameter> using the txtRefine text box.

**Updated aspx:**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="VendorsSDS" runat="server"        
    SelectCommand="Select VNMKVPRE||VNMKVNBR as VendorID, vnmdesc||' - '||VNMKVPRE||VNMKVNBR as vnmdesc    from trmsd.avnmp   where VNMST = 'A' and not trim(vnmdesc) = '' and vnmkvpre in ( 'R', 'V', 'X')  order by VNMDESC ">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtRefine" Name="?" PropertyName="Text" defaultvalue=""/>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**Updated vb:**

```
    Protected Sub btnRefine_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRefine.Click

    '   2020-Jul-27 Removed
    '   VendorsSDS.SelectCommand = "Select VNMKVPRE||VNMKVNBR as VendorID, vnmdesc||' - '||VNMKVPRE||VNMKVNBR as vnmdesc    from trmsd.avnmp   where VNMST = 'A' and not trim(vnmdesc) = '' and vnmkvpre in ('R', 'V', 'X') and vnmdesc like '%" & UCase(Trim(txtRefine.Text)) & "%' order by VNMDESC "        

    '
    '   2020-Jul-27  Added sqlinjection monitoring
    '
    Dim wParm As String = Me.txtRefine.Text
    If oSec.IsInputOk(wParm) Then
        Me.txtRefine.Text = wParm
        '
        '   2020-Jul-27 Apply sql parameter usage
        '
        VendorsSDS.SelectCommand = "Select VNMKVPRE||VNMKVNBR as VendorID, vnmdesc||' - '||VNMKVPRE||VNMKVNBR as vnmdesc    from trmsd.avnmp   where VNMST = 'A' and not trim(vnmdesc) = '' and vnmkvpre in ('R', 'V', 'X') and vnmdesc like ('%' & ? & '%') order by VNMDESC "
        VendorsSDS.DataBind()
        ListBox1.DataBind()
    Else
        Me.txtRefine.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

I've tried several combinations of how to apply the wildcard selection.  Some posts said to use & and others said +.  Both of these strategies fail no matter the combination when the binding happens:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'SQL0104: Token '%' was not valid. Valid tokens: (.
```

Cause . . . . . :   A syntax error was detected at token '%'.  Token '%' is not a valid token.

Thus none of the below work and I need help in filling in my knowledge gap from those smarter than me.

```
and vnmdesc like '%' + ? + '%'
and vnmdesc like ('%' + ? + '%') 
and vnmdesc like ('%' & ? & '%') 
and vnmdesc like ('%?%')
```

Lastly, when the page first displays, it's supposed to show all records that are not blank using the initial sql in the sqldatassource, but that's not working now either with the updated sqldatasource.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are WIDE-OPEN to SQL-Injection.  Read up on parameterizing your queries.  Don't use any textbox data direct from the web source.  You can get in big trouble.  Also, your select query looks strange with the || (double-pipe) characters.

Comment: DRapp ... It was my understanding that using a parameterized query would negate the sql injection problem. In the vb codebehind I am doing elementary scrubbing prior to updating the parameterized query.  Is there something else that needs to be done? Would you otherwise recommend a different strategy for me to use to populate a listbox from a wildcard selection?  I'm trying to fix this issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

You actually have two mistakes, which are making it more-difficult to solve.

1. Your parameter name cannot be `?`.  Pick any name, like this:

   ```
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtRefine"
    Name="vnmdescription" PropertyName="Text" defaultvalue=""/>
   ```
2. Your SQL was very close, but `&` is a concatenator for VB.NET.  SQL uses `+` like this:

   ```vb
   VendorsSDS.SelectCommand = "SELECT VNMKVPRE||VNMKVNBR as VendorID, vnmdesc||' - '||VNMKVPRE||VNMKVNBR as vnmdesc
      FROM trmsd.avnmp
      WHERE VNMST = 'A' and not trim(vnmdesc) = '' and vnmkvpre in ('R', 'V', 'X') 
        and vnmdesc like ('%' + ? + '%')
      ORDER BY vnmdesc"
   ```

For more info, MSDN docs.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectparameters?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: tgolisch - I re-tested with your suggestions and I got similar errors still.  As I mentioned at the top of this post, I'm using OleDb and not Sql ... so the @parms will not work in this case.

Comment: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'SQL0206: Column or global variable (at) VNMDESCRIPTION not found.  Cause . . . . . :   (at)VNMDESCRIPTION was not found as a column of table *N in *N and was not found as a global variable in *N. If the table is *N, (at)VNMDESCRIPTION is not a column of any table or view that can be referenced.

Comment: Sorry.  Change the `(at)vnmdescription` to just a `?`

Answer (score 0):

After another day of trying various ideas... the following was the answer:

**On the vb side:**

```
CONCAT(CONCAT('%', ?), '%')
```

Thank you to everyone who tried to help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

Parameterizing queries actually means using the parameters part of the SQL command object.  When writing a query, do not concatenate strings together to one long string.  Lets say you have a person's name like O'Brian where there is a quote in the name.  Now you have a failing query because of mismatched quotes.

Different databases (yours not so indicated, such as MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, etc.) allow naming parameters.  Others use the "?" as place-holders for the parameters, and the parameters need to be added in the same order as the "?" place-holder.

Additionally, for the wildcard searches by using the "%" before/after text being sought CAN be added to the string at time of adding the parameter as so needed.

As mentioned in my original comment, I have no idea what your "||" pipe characters are for so I will make up a sample query and parameters example for you.  Note, the parameters begin done in this manner don't matter the data type such as date, date/time, string, number, etc.  You are not concatenating the strings together.

(note, the formatting of the SQL statement on multiple rows is incorrect syntax for VB, just doing for readability here)

```
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
cmd.CommandText = 
"SELECT whateverColumn 
   FROM YourTable 
   WHERE ColumnBeingFiltered = ? 
     and SomeCityColumn = ?"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("parmForFirstWhereCondition", variableFromYourCleansedWebPost )

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("parmForCity", anotherVariableFromPost )
```

Notice the query is what it is... the "?" are the place-holders for the parameter.  I then add  the parameter in order.  I can name them for MY purposes of reference, so if I needed to change them, such as in a loop, I could then refer to them as

```
cmd.Parameters["parmForCity"].Value = "Boston"
```

If you are working with other databases such as SQL-Server that allow naming the parameters, you can name the place-holder fields such as...

```
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
cmd.CommandText = 
"SELECT whateverColumn 
   FROM YourTable 
   WHERE ColumnBeingFiltered = @parmForFirstWhereCondition 
     and SomeCityColumn LIKE @parmForCity 
     and Population > @parmNumber"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("parmNumber", 125000 )
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("parmForCity", "%" & anotherVariableFromPost & "%")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("parmForFirstWhereCondition", variableFromYourCleansedWebPost )
```

Notice in this second query, I also did example of adding the "%" for wildcard search of the parameter, added a 3rd parameter which was numeric based, and also changed the order of the parameters just to show the difference that different SQL engines allow when NAMING parameters.  the "@" in SQL server is recognized as a named parameter, but the actual parameter name does NOT use the "@".  Also, I try to always prefix the parameter name with either "p" or "parm" to differentiate between an actual column vs the parameter.   Ex:  where "firstName = firstName"  vs "firstName = @parmFirstName", then there is no ambiguity when looking at the query.

Does this help clarify parameterizing queries for you now.